# Use of overloaded(optional) constructor in repository pattern MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern

I am following below article and repository pattern.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I am confused at one point, optional contructor defined in controller.

```
public StudentController(IStudentRepository studentRepository)
{
    this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
}
```

Even if, I remove that - code works well. what is use of this constructor. As we are assing new context object in main default constructor.

Comment: This is dependency injection with an IOC container. The idea is to have a repository (generic) and then a service layer that access the repository. Then you can inject the interfaces into the constructor to do work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I have any example code snipplet please?

Comment: here's a link that implements a generic repository using ninject as an Inversion of Control (IOC) container (http://codetrek.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/generic-repository-ninject/). The example uses entity framework. A more thorough example will depend on which type of database you use.

Comment: At this point, stay away form a generic repository. It has only limited usage. Outside that usage it's basically an anti pattern

Answer (score 0):

The optional ctor doesn't create a new context, while the optional one does.  The context is set in the StudentRepository's ctor.

Comment: @Keyur...There really is no snippet to give you - it's all in the tutorial. The StudentController has to instantiate a StudentRepository and the StudentRepository needs a context. So, if the StudentRepository isn't injected, it has to create one. The StudentRepository has one ctor and it requires a context.

Answer (score 0):

This constructor allows you to pass in a different implementation of the studentRepository. Note that it accepts an interface, not a concrete implementation of the repository. This can be useful for unit testing where you can pass in a fake repository that does not need to access a database. You can also use this constructor with dependency injection.